# PHP protected area in switch

Tags: php, html

At the moment i create an simple login system with PHP.

My index.php consists of a switch sconstruction. Here is the switch construction.

```
switch($content){
     case "home":
         include "include/home/home.html";
         break;
     case "login":
         include "include/login-logout-regestrieren/login.html";
         break;
     case "logout":
         include "include/login-logout-regestrieren/logout.html";
         break;
     case "regestrieren":
         include "include/login-logout-regestrieren/regestrieren.html";
         break;
     default: 
         include "include/home/home.html";
}
```

Now i want to create into this switch an protected area like this:

```
switch($content){
     case "home":
         include "include/home/home.html";
         break;
     case "login":
         include "include/login-logout-regestrieren/login.html";
         break;
     case "logout":
         include "include/login-logout-regestrieren/logout.html";
         break;
     case "regestrieren":
         include "include/login-logout-regestrieren/regestrieren.html";
         break;
         if($protected == TRUE){
             case "example":
                 include "include/login-logout-regestrieren/example.html";
                 break; 
         }
             default: 
                  include "include/home/home.html";
}
```

If i do that i get an error. Is this useless? 
My idea was to create some "new" links for the users that are logged in. And i thought i protect the links with this easy if construct.

Comment: Put your if inside your case statement. The break needs also to be between the if-scope then (so the default case will still execute if needed).

Comment: Wow... thats simple. :D Thanks, you helped me alot. Now i have one more question. THe page (protected.html) is as example the page that only logged in users can see. Should i check in "protected.html" the variable again?

Comment: You cannot check that in HTML, you need php for that.

Comment: please try explain it.. your question is unclear

Comment: Nooo im fine. I thought i can still open the page over the url like this: index.php?content=protected, but i come to the index page and the index page will give an error :) im fine thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
switch($content){
    case "home":
        include "include/home/home.html";
        break;
    case "login":
        include "include/login-logout-regestrieren/login.html";
        break;
    case "logout":
        include "include/login-logout-regestrieren/logout.html";
        break;
    case "regestrieren":
        include "include/login-logout-regestrieren/regestrieren.html";
        break;                
    case "example":
        if($protected == TRUE){
            include "include/login-logout-regestrieren/example.html";
            break;
        }
   default: 
       include "include/home/home.html";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Sarath's answer has a logic flaw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29029977/3000179), which needs to be addressed.

For example, `$protected` is `false` and `$content == 'example'`. I will simply get no page included. This is because `break;` will make your flow come out of the `switch()` and carry on with page execution. At the moment, `break;` will be called if `$content == 'example'`. This isn't good for user experience - I'd assume you'd want to `include "include/home/home.html"` and give the illusion of a non-authenticated user that `example` doesn't exist.

You need to wrap your `break;` within your `$protected` if statement .

```
switch ($content) {
    case "home":
        include "include/home/home.html";
        break;
    case "login":
        include "include/login-logout-regestrieren/login.html";
        break;
    case "logout":
        include "include/login-logout-regestrieren/logout.html";
        break;
    case "regestrieren":
        include "include/login-logout-regestrieren/regestrieren.html";
        break;
    case "example":
        if ($protected == TRUE) {
            include "include/login-logout-regestrieren/example.html";
            break;
        }
    default:
        include "include/home/home.html";
        break;
}
```

Comment: @Sarath Sure... I can't stop you :)